# Rename Local Database tables in SQL with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, rename, local-database

I have created a local database `db.mdf` in VS2010 asp.net website. In there are a few tables.

Now I need to rename the tables.  But query designer doesn't let me. How do I rename those tables?

Comment: may be this will help you
select table in server explorer press f2 or rename table by right click option.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Server Explorer, right-click the table you want to rename and choose Open Table Definition from the shortcut menu.

The table opens in the Table Definition window of Table Designer.
2. Right-click the table in the Table Definition window and choose Properties from the shortcut menu.
3. In the field for the Name value in the Properties window, type a new name for the table.

1. To cancel this action, press the ESC key before leaving this field.
2. From the File menu choose Save table name.

Answer (score 0):

Rename database tables in Visual Studio:

1. Server Explorer
2. Right click on the tables
3. Click the Edit Table Schema

Answer (score 0):

The answers did not work for me in Visual Studio 2017. The Table field is locked for some reason.

What worked for me is the following. In the `T-SQL` tab change the entry

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTableName] (
```

Then select `Update` (top-left). It worked for me.